# How to re-submit form data in custom module?

Tags: magento2, php, module, template, controllers

I want to get `post data` in phtml . In case form data not save then show error and already fill form .

```
 <form class="trail-register-form" 
       action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getUrl().'xxxxxxx/post/register/'); ?>" 
       method="post" 
       enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <input type="text" name="xxxxx_vehicle_name" placeholder="Vehicle Name" required>
```

**controller.php**

```
$model->setData('xxxx_name', $post['xxxx_name']);
$id =$model->save()
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can use ***DataPersistor*** `Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface`  .

This class can save request data and share that to another url. ***DataPersistor***  is just like a session variable.

First, you have to save request data to a data persistor

using to a `dataPersistor`  variable.

```
 $this->dataPersistor->set('my_request', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
```

Here the variable name is **my_request**.

Now, at  your form block 
  using `Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface` you can  fetch that  variable value

```
 $this->dataPersistor->get('my_request');
```

ALso, after  get that variable value, you have to clear that variable from dataPersistor  using `$this->dataPersistor->clear('my_request')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Registry**

> \Magento\Framework\Registry.

You can save data by using

```
$this->registry->register('your_variable', $this->getRequest()->getParams()).
```

You can fetch data by using

```
$this->registry->registry('your_variable').
```

Comment: Registry is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

1. Update

   `$this->getUrl().'xxxxxxx/post/register/`

   to

   `$block->getUrl("xxxxxxx/post/register/")`
2. controller.php

   ```
   $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
   if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
       $xxxx_name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('xxxxx_vehicle_name'); 
       if(!empty($xxxx_name)) {
           try{
               $model->load('id_here'); //you load your model first. 
               $model->setData('xxxx_name', $xxxx_name);
               $model->save();
           }catch (\Exception $e) {
               $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
           }

       }else {
           $message = __('Please fill in the field');
           $this->_messageManager->addError($message);
           $resultRedirect->setRefererUrl();
           return $resultRedirect;
       }   
   }else {
       $resultRedirect->setRefererUrl();
       return $resultRedirect;    
   }

   // don't forget to inject dependencies of "messageManager", "ResultFactory", "logger"
   ```